# Timer Slows down in Service when device screen lock

Tags: android, service, wakelock

I am using a countdown timer in a service.The timer goes on like that 01,02,03,.... Everything works fine.But when the device screen lock the timer becomes slow but still running.I am using the PowerManager but not working.PowerManager only works when the USB cable connected to the PC but when i remove the device from PC timer slows down.I do not know why this problem arises.Please help me to sort out this problem.Thank in advace.Below is my code.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "whatever");
        wl.acquire();

        }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        flagVibrate=intent.getBooleanExtra("FlagVibrate",false);
        if(mStartTime == 0L){
            mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);

        }
    }

        @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);

        stopSelf();
        wl.release();
    }
        private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {

        final long start = mStartTime;
        long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()- start;

        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int stopTime = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        GuardMeActivity.timerView.setText("" + minutes + ":"
                              + String.format("%02d", seconds));

        timerStop1 = minutes + ":"
                  + String.format("%02d", seconds);



        }

}

};
```

Comment: Have you given `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` permission in manifest ?

Comment: Yes i already gave this permission.The PowerManager only works when the USB cable connected to the PC but when i remove the device from PC timer slows down.

Comment: @Deepak, I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, I have resolved the issue but this problem came before 6 years so I forgot what I did.. Sorry bro

Answer (score 2):

Write down following code in your `GuardMeActivity` activity's `onResume()` method and check the result.

Files to import

```
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;

Window window = this.getWindow();
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: Sorry !! Not working :( 
Actually timer slows down only when the device screen locks otherwise everything is working fine.

Comment: Which device you are using ?

Comment: I am using Nexus tab..Can u please tell me the package name to import LayoutParams class.So many packages are shown.

Comment: PowerManager only works when the USB cable connected to the PC but when i remove the device from PC timer slows down.I do not know why this problem arises.